# d3.js change color and size on line graph dot on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, data-visualization

I made a line graph with d3.js (see the attached image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8lV1.png)).

I managed to insert tooltips on graph dots when mouseover.
I'd like to change color and size of dots too. I tried in many ways but it seems really difficult. Any help?
Here is the piece of code:

```
  svg.selectAll("dot")    
    .data(data)         
    .enter().append("circle")                               
    .attr("r", 5.5)
    .style("fill", "#fff8ee")    
       .style("opacity", .8)      // set the element opacity
.style("stroke", "#f93")    // set the line colour
 .style("stroke-width", 3.5) 
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })       
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.close); })     
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {   

        div.transition()        
            .duration(70)      
            .style("opacity", .7)

             ;      
        div .html(formatTime(d.date) + "<br/>"  + d.close)  
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
        })                  
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
        div.transition()        
            .duration(200)      
            .style("opacity", 0);   
    });
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just set color and size in the handlers:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("r", 10).style("fill", "red");
})                  
.on("mouseout", function(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("r", 5.5).style("fill", "#fff8ee");
});
```

Comment: The additional `d3.select(this)...` would be placed inside the `mouseover` and `mouseout` handlers like I have illustrated.

Comment: For some reason, `this` returned `null` to me. Using `d3.event.target` instead worked.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why, but while `d3.select(this)` used to work, it doesn't anymore. I now use `d3.select(event.currentTarget)`.

So, if we consider `svg` as the graph and all its circles being red by default, we can change the color of the circles to green on `mouseover` and return the color to red on `mouseout` like this:

```
svg.on("mouseover", function(d){
d3.select(event.currentTarget)
.style("fill", "green");
})
.on("mouseout", function(d){
d3.select(event.currentTarget)
.style("fill", "red");
});
```

Comment: Your assumption is wrong: the binding of `this` still works as documented and as laid out in the accepted answer. See https://jsfiddle.net/4xjnfqL7/2/ for a working demo. Of course, your approach works too, although it is unnecessarily complicated. The context of your code might be significant as it could change the binding of `this` but since you did not provide any of that I'd consider this not helpful.

Comment: Thanks altocumulus. The code in the accepted answer isn't quite same as that in your jsfiddle. I've updated my own code to match that in your jsfiddle,and I hope it's useful to somebody.

Comment: The code in the fiddle is pretty much identical to the one in the accepted answer. I added two log statements which do not have any side-effects, though. The way your answer is now is totally wrong and is not going to work; you are trying to select a boolean value! This is not equivalent to what I have in the fiddle nor does it match the question nor the accepted answer.

Comment: Unless you have a working demo for your claims that `d3.select(this)` is not working anymore I suggest you rethink the post and consider deleting it altogether.

Comment: This answer worked for me, but `d3.select(this)` didn't. I'm using `https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js` version.

Comment: Remember, arrow functions do not have their own `this` as compared with regular functions.

Comment: Thanks ABCD.ca. Forgetting the peculiar absence of `this` from arrow functions is a pit into which I've fallen all too often.